# How to get the all booking list from bookeo api?

Tags: php, web-services

I am new to the bookeo booking API and I do not understand how I can get the booking list using php ..

https://www.bookeo.com/apiref/index.html#!/Bookings/bookings_get

Comment: you need to construct a HTTP request. Within PHP, this can be done using any HTTP client library, such as cURL

Answer (score 0):

````
1.The simplest way to launch a request is use the function: file_get_contents. But it only works for GET method.

2.Otherwise,you can use the curl library which is very powerful.

```
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "API URL");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   $output = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   print_r($output);
```

The more detail usage you can google it.
````